# Prove this is a subalgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

Let $\phi, \psi$ be two homomorphisms $A\rightarrow B$ of algebras $A$ and $B$.
Prove $E = \{a\in A : \phi(a) = \psi(a)\}$ is a subalgebra of $A$.

I'm not quite sure what I even have to show.  In my notes it says that the algebra $B$ is a subalgebra of $A$ if $A \subset B$ (is that backwards? I feel like it should be $B \subset A$) and all operations $f_B$ of $B$ are the restrictions of the corresponding operations $f_A$, but I think I found online that I just need to show that the product of any two elements of $A$ is in $A$.  I obviously prefer to use the definition from class, but it is way more confusing.

I think the way to approach this is to take two elements $b,c \in E$ then $\phi(b) = \psi(b)$ and $\phi(c) = \psi(c)$.  We know that since $\phi$ and $\psi$ are homormorphisms they preserve all operations so for any $f$ we have $\phi(f(b)) = f(\phi(b)) = f(\psi(b)) = \psi(f(b))$.  I have no idea what to do.

Then for part b, we are asked to show that if $X \subset A$ generates $A$ and $\phi(a) = \psi(a) \forall a \in X$ then $\phi = \psi$.

I think this can be done by contradiction, i.e. suppose that $\phi \neq \psi$.  Then there exists $b \in A$ such that $\phi(b) - \psi(b) \neq 0$.  Since $A$ is generated by $X$, $b$ can be written as some combination of elements $x_i \in X$.  I'm not sure I understand what that looks like so I may be wrong from here on out.  Then $\phi(b) = \phi( \sum{c_ix_i}) = \sum{\phi(c_ix_i)} = \sum{c_i\phi(x_i)} = \sum{c_i\psi(x_i)} = \sum{\psi(c_ix_i)} = \psi(\sum{c_ix_i}) = \psi(b)$

Comment: You do not state to have a ring structure or something similar, so what's 0 in those algebras? And what are those operations of sum and product? Shouldn't they be replaced by arbitrary operations?

Comment: can you prove these statements for groups? for rings? If you can, your problem seems to be mostly notational. If you can't, maybe you're not yet ready for universal algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, you need to show that if $f$ is an $n$-ary operation on the type of these algebras, and $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in E$, then $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in E$.
But in these conditions,
\begin{align}
\phi(f(a_1,\ldots,a_n))
&= f(\phi(a_1),\ldots,\phi(a_n))\tag{$\because\phi$ is a homomorphism}\\
&= f(\psi(a_1),\ldots,\psi(a_n))\tag{$\because a_1, \ldots, a_n \in E$}\\
&= \psi(f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)),\tag{$\because\psi$ is a homomorphism}
\end{align}
whence $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in E$.

For the second part, if $b \in A$, arbitrary and $A$ is generated by $X$, then there exists a term on the type of $A$ (a composition of fundamental operations) such that
$$b = t(a_1, \ldots, a_k),$$
with $a_1, \ldots, a_k \in X$.
With a reasoning similar to the previous one, you can conclude that $\phi(b)=\psi(b)$ (you must understand that homomorphisms preserve compositions of the operations, so they preserve term functions).

Comment: So just to check, for part (b) we have that $b = t(a_1,...,a_k)$ so $\phi(b) = \phi(t(a_1,...,a_n)) = t(\phi(a_1), ..., \phi(a_n)) = t(\psi(a_1,..,a_n)) = \psi(t(a_1,..,a_n)) = \psi(b)$ and this holds for all $b$ in $A$

Comment: On a similar note, I want to show that if $X \subset A$ and $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ a homomorphism then for any subset $X \subset A$, $\phi(\langle X \rangle) = \langle \phi(X) \rangle$.  Could you tell me if I am going about this correctly because it seems very similar.  Let $X = a_1, ..., a_n$ then any element in $A$ is of the form $t(a_1,...,a_n)$ so $\phi(t(a_1,..a_n)) = t(\phi(a_1),...,\phi(a_n))$ so it is a term of things from $\phi(X)$ so $\phi(\langle X \rangle) \subset \langle \phi(X) \rangle$.  Then I want to show the opposite inclusion, which I will do in the next comment

Comment: Let $a \in \langle \phi(X) \rangle$.  Then $a = t(\phi(a_)1, ..., \phi(a_n ))$ (This part is iffy. I don't know if thats right at all).  Then $a = t(\phi(a_1), ..., \phi(a_n )) = \phi(t(a_1,...,a_n)) $ so it is in the set $\phi(\langle X \rangle)$ so we have both inclusions so they must be equal.  Is that correct

Comment: @VinnyChase It all seems good to me. Except that, in the first comment should be $t(\psi(a_1),\ldots,\psi(a_n))$ where you wrote $t(\psi(a_1,\ldots,a_n))$ and I suppose in the last one you swapped the closing parenthesis with the underscore resulting in $\phi(a_)1$ where it should be $\phi(a_1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Using (reverse) Cohn's notation, let $\omega$ be an $n$-ary operation defined on $A$ and $B$; since $\phi$ and $\psi$ are homomorphisms, for $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\in A$,
$$
\phi(\omega a_1a_2\dots a_n)=\omega\phi(a_1)\phi(a_2)\dots\phi(a_n)
$$
and similarly for $\psi$.

If $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\in E$, then
$$
\phi(\omega a_1a_2\dots a_n)=\omega\phi(a_1)\phi(a_2)\dots\phi(a_n)
=
\omega\psi(a_1)\psi(a_2)\dots\psi(a_n)=\psi(\omega a_1a_2\dots a_n)
$$
and therefore $\omega a_1a_2\dots a_n\in E$. Since this works for every operation on $A$, we conclude that $E$ is a subalgebra.